# "Tiling" file manager and nothing else

Tags: 16.04, filemanager, budgie

I am using 16.04 LTS, Budgie Desktop, right now one of my main uses of File Manager is that I take a file out and either send it over discord or over a browser. Sadly when I open a browser/discord the file manager hides no matter what.

How do I make it stick that I don't want a file manager to hide from view until I close it? "Always on top" option seems to only work for a single instance of File Manager. As soon as I close it down, the default is loaded and it hides again.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using? Have you tried copy-pasting the path instead?

Comment: @WJAndrea copy pasting path to what? Does stuff like facebook messenger support posting a path? Same with other applications that use drag-in

Comment: oh, you're using drag-and-drop. I wasn't sure if you were using the "Browse" dialog, which would support pasting a path.